# Angular 2 form reset() not resetting values _submitted or submitted

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Is there a way so form.reset() also resets values form.submitted to false again? This is annoying in my case as I use form.submitted as condition to show validation error in template. This means validation errors show up after form is cleared (reset).

template:

```
<form ... #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && submitProduct(f)>
  <input type="text" name="productName" [(ngModel)]="product.name" #productName="ngModel" required>
  <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !productName.valid">Product name is required</div>
  <button type="submit" value="true" >Submit Request</button>
</form>
```

component:

```
submitProduct(form: NgForm) {
    this.productService.createProduct(this.product).subscribe(data => {
        form.reset();
        // HERE annoyingly validation errors show up on empty form.
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: can you do form.markAsPristine();

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Use

```
form.resetForm();
```

instead. This sets submitted to false and pristine to true.

Answer (score 1):

Use native reset button type:

```
<button type="reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have the `f.form.valid && submitProduct` in the submit.

```
<form ... #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitProduct(f)>
...
<button type="submit" value="true" [disabled]="!f.valid">Submit Request</button>
```

Also call [resetForm](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgForm-directive.html#!#resetForm-anchor) to make it pristine again.

```
form.resetForm();
```